# Fetch contacts in alphabetical order in android?

Tags: android, mysql

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, "(" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?) AND " + Data.CONTACT_ID + " IN (SELECT " + Contacts._ID + " FROM contacts)", new String[] {Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE  }, Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

I want to fetch my contacts in alphabetical order but this query fetches them in non-alphabetical order. i don't know where to attach asc order in this query.Please help

Answer (score 2):

The fifth parameter is sortOrder. You're passing `Data.CONTACT_ID`.

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, "(" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?) AND " + Data.CONTACT_ID + " IN (SELECT " + Contacts._ID + " FROM contacts)", new String[] {Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE  }, Data.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
```

Comment: thanks for your response, its working fine but its taking more time than my last query

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel my answer helped you move forward and answered your question, will you please mark it as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

|*| Add Below Line in 5 parameter of query as it is for Sort-Order.

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
```

|*| Optimised : Alphabetically get Display Name and Number with label and Photo Thumbnail in one query :

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor contctKsrVar = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},
            null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```